# Wrap relevant tags with {{ compress js }} and {{ compress css }}

Tags: django, django-compressor

Is there a way to wrap automatically all the relevant tags (i. e. script, style, link rel=stylesheet) with django_compressor tags?

Comment: Hm, I don't think so...what problem are you trying to solve? (Are you also automatically including script or style tags or something?) What I mean is, why not just add the compress tags to your base template?

Comment: @peppergrower I'm converting existing legacy app and it have many places with styles/scripts in it. So I can't just add them to base template.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: updated in line with Chris Pratt's comment. Thanks Chris.

Make use of template blocks in your base.html to define {% extra_js %} and {% extra_css %} blocks, then put *those* blocks inside django-compressor blocks. You may also want to have {% extra_js_nocompress %} and {% extra_css_nocompress %} blocks, too, for stuff that explodes inside compressor (eg Twitter Bootstrap)

So, somewhere in your base.html (and ideally with CSS high up and JS low down):

```
{% compress css%}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}foo/bar.css">
   <!-- any other global CSS here too -->
{% endcompress %}

{% compress css%}
   {% block extra_css %}{% endblock %}
{% endcompress %}

{% block extra_css_nocompress %}{% endblock %}



{% compress js%}
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/waa/baa.js"></script>
   <!-- any other global JS here too -->
{% endcompress %}

{% compress js%}
   {% block extra_js %}{% endblock %}
{% endcompress %}

{% block extra_js_nocompress %}{% endblock %}
```

Then, in your templates, if the template extends base.html, you can shuffle all your in-template CSS and JS into these blocks (while still keeping them in the template that needs them)

Comment: Don't put your "extra" block inside the same compress block as your global styles. If you do, an entirely separate CSS file will be generated containing the same base style the user has *already* downloaded, plus the extra stuff. You're essentially forcing the download of the same style over and over again. Put it in its own compress block after the compress block with the global style.

Comment: Oh, that's very interesting. Thanks for the tip. Have reworked my answer

Comment: It's technically an extra request (2 compressed CSS files instead of one), but one  (and likely the largest) should be cached after the first page load. So, for the most part, you still have just one new request, but it's *much* lighter now.